# Protect object inside closure from being modified from outside

Tags: javascript

I have created this object in order to be able to store data in it, that has some level of protection. Anyone can get it, and anyone can set it as long as the new data passes validation.

```
MF.factory = new function(){
    var data = {
        SITE_URL: document.URL.replace(/(https?:\/\/.+?)\/.*/, '$1'),
        xhrSettings: {
            type: 'GET',
            error: function(){},
            response: function(){},
            max_upload_file_size: 8388608
        }
    }
    this.get = function(key){
        return data[key];
    }
    this.set = {
        xhrSettings: {
            type: function(type){if(type in {POST:0,GET:0,PUT:0}) data.xhrSettings.type = type;},
            error: function(func){if(typeof func === 'function') data.xhrSettings.error = func;},
            response: function(func){if(typeof func === 'function') data.xhrSettings.response = func;},
            max_upload_file_size: function(size){if(!isNaN(size)) data.xhrSettings.max_upload_file_size = size;}
        }
    }
};
```

For example now I can get `SITE_URL`, but I cannot set it. This is the kind of restriction I am looking for. I can set `xhrSettings.type` as long as it is either POST, GET or PUT.

```
MF.factory.set.xhrSettings.type("DGD"); // No effect
MF.factory.set.xhrSettings.type("POST"); // data.xhrSettings.type = "POST"
```

However if I do this

```
a = MF.factory.get('xhrSettings');
a.type = "DGD";
console.log(MF.factory.get('xhrSettings'));
```

I see that the object inside `data` has changed, which renders my whole concept useless. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what **[`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)** is for.

From MDN:

> The Object.freeze() method freezes an object: that is, prevents new
>   properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from
>   being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their
>   enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed. In
>   essence the object is made effectively immutable. The method returns
>   the object being frozen.

**Note**: Object.freeze() is not supported in IE v8 and below.

Comment: @Andy - Yes, thanks for pointing out. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: But isn't that going to make the object unchangeable even with my `set` function, that is supposed to change it, but validate incoming data first?

Comment: It's in the docs but sometimes people don't get that far down the page ;)

Comment: @php_nub_qq - Yes it will make the object totally immutable.

Comment: Well how would I change it then? I mean with valid set data?

Comment: @php_nub_qq - a) Restructure your app so that reader scopes are passed a frozen copy of the object - OR - b) Don't expose the setter outside the namespace, return only the getter as part of the object's methods.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be rather than returning objects, return properties that themselves can be namespaced for readability:

```
  type = MF.factory.get( 'xhrSettings.type');
  type = "DGD";
  console.log(MF.factory.get('xhrSettings.type'));
```

This means your `data` object has flat properties:

```
var data = {
    SITE_URL: document.URL.replace(/(https?:\/\/.+?)\/.*/, '$1'),
    "xhrSettings.type": 'GET',
    "xhrSettings.error": Function.prototype,
    "xhrSettings.max_upload_file_size": 8388608
}
```

etc.

And `set` becomes an actual `function` that checks which property is trying to be set and does whatever you want (return and ignore, throw an error, etc)

Comment: `MF.factory.get( 'xhrSettings.type');` returns `undefined` for me :/

Comment: Well, yeah, you'd have to change your code. Your `data` object would need to have raw properties on it. I've updated the answer to illustrate this.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but I need to be able to return whole objects from `data`, for extending other objects and stuff

Comment: Then clone the object in `get`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.freeze(objectName);
```

where "objectName" is the name of the object you want to freeze.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying `this.get` to the following

```
this.get = function(key){
    return (data[key] instanceof Object) ? Object.create(data[key]) : data[key];
}
```

Comment: this code will not work for arrays, though. `data.props = [1,2,3]; x.get('props); // [undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Comment: @c69 it does work for me. It returns an object rather than an array but the key-value pairs are the same so I believe that is not a problem, unless you want to use the `Array.prototype` in which case I'd need to tweak it a little further http://jsfiddle.net/8BNF3/

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to return a copy of your object.

With underscore/lodash you can use `_.clone()`, so:

```
this.get = function(key){
    return _.clone(data[key]);
}
```

Keep in mind, though that clone is doing only a shallow copy. So, if you need it deep, you can  abuse jquery `extend` for this, and add check for arrays:

```
this.get = function(key){
    var x = data[key];
    return typeof x !== 'object' ? x :
        $.extend(true, (Array.isArray(x) ? [] : {}), x);
}
```

this second solution is still not perfect, as it would not handle circular objects, and there might be problems with cloning getters/setters, etc. But for simple cases even the first solution would be ok.